# Point whose neighbourhood is contained in a certain sphere of radius r has Gaussian curvature greater than $\frac{1}{r^2}$?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

I am doing a question which asks one to show that is a compact, regular surface $\Sigma$ has Gaussian curvature $K < \frac{1}{r^2}$, then $\text{diam}(\Sigma) > r$. The given solution is the following:
[image]

I don't understand how they concluded that $K(q) \geq s^{-2}$ if $\Sigma$ is contained in $\overline{B}_s(p)$. Intuitively this is clear, but I can't seem to find a theorem that states something like this explicitly. Where can I find such a result?

Comment: One standard proof that $K(q) \geq s^{-2} \geq r^{-2}$ ([sic]; the inequalities in the image are backward) is to consider the curvatures of normal sections to $\Sigma$ at $q$. (In elementary books on differential geometry, the detailed argument usually occurs when one shows a compact surface in Euclidean three-space has a point of positive Gaussian curvature.)